# How to add UIView with indicator over UITableView in IPhone app

Tags: iphone, uitableview, authentication

In my app, I have made SignIn page for user sign-in. For this, i have used UIViewController with Subclass of UITableViewController.

I have used two rows with grouped tableview. I want to place UIView with indicator over tableview after user tapped SignIn button. If user clicked signin button, i want to show message like "loading" with spinner over tableview.

[image: Login]

I have designed the above image. but how to achieve the below image after tapped signin button?

[image: after login]

Please help in this regards and if any sample code means its very helpful to me.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply create a UIView and style it as you want, placing it above the login section, in your code when you awake from nib you make sure you set that view to be hidden.

When you tap login you simply toggle the table cells to display nothing and switch the loading view to not hide anymore.

Answer (score 1):

put the second view above and fade it in with an animation. You can simply create both in Interface Builder and make Outlets for both. Just set the alpha value of the second one to `0.0`

Basically you would have a login button:

```
- (void)doMyLoginWithUsername:(NSString*)uname password:(NSString*)pwd {
    // first show the loading screen …
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{ 
        mySecondLogginInView.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
    // meanwhile check if the username matches the password
    // if not simply set mySecondLogginInView.alpha = 0.0;
}
```